# Combining transformations of SVG using D3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

So I'm new to d3 and I'm drawing multiple groups of shapes based on data. Something like

```
    polygons = d3.selecctAll("g").data(data);
```

Now, I want to translate and scale the groups, but `polygons.attr("scale" ...)` only scales around the origin of the canvas when I want it to scale around the center of the group. So if a group was centered at `(cx, cy)`, then I need something like `transate(-cx, -cy)`, `scale(2.0)`, `translate(cx, cy)` in that order. I also want to translate the group once more afterwards. However, I can only do one scale then translate using

```
    polygons.attr("transfrom", "translate(...) + " " + scale(...)");
```

How would I stack transformations in the order I choose? Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. You can have as many transformations as you like, e.g. `translate(...)scale(...)translate(...)scale(...)`.

Comment: Tried that, it works! Looks like I tried it before, but I mistyped something so it didn't work. Thanks!